# Install ubuntu touch on a LG e400

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, arm

I want my old phone to run wxtoimg, which is available for linux, even for ARM.

The problem is that the phone has Android 2.3.6 installed and the default installation guide fails in several steps....
(The backup step, the bootmanager unlocking step freezes the device, the flashing step returns no image for the device)

My Android device is a rooted lg e400 with 8gb sdcard.

How can I install an ARM version of ubuntu or ubuntu touch on it?

The installation guide I tried
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/